# Ordering SQLAlchemy Foreign Objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm a noob to SQL Alchemy and come from .NET, so I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this one.  I have two classes and it is a one to many relationship, so I'd expect to be able to sort the returned episodes, but I can't figure out the right way to do this.  What is below reults in:

```
instrumented list has not attribute 'order_by'
```

I know I'm missing something in regards to the query, but I'd expect the child elements to be available to me.  I know I can query again to just get the episodes with the correct show_id, but that defeats the purpose of having the relationship, right?  Thanks for the help!

Objects:

```
    class Show(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'show'
    show_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    show_name = Column(String)
    first_aired = Column(Date)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    banner = Column(String)
    show_directory = Column(String)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.show_name, self.show_id)


class Episode(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'episode'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    show_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('show.show_id'))
    show = relationship(Show, backref=backref('episodes', uselist=True))
    season_number = Column(Integer)
    episode_number = Column(Integer)
    episode_name = Column(String)
    air_date = Column(Date)
    status = Column(String, default='Retrieved')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s s%se%s" % (self.show.show_name, str(self.season_number).zfill(2), str(self.episode_number).zfill(2))

    def get_episode_name(self):
        return self.episode_name.replace('<','').replace('>','')
```

Python:

```
current_show = s.query(Show).filter(Show.show_id == show_id).first()

current_episodes = current_show.episodes.order_by(Episode.season_number.desc()).order_by(Episode.episode_number.desc())
```

Comment: See the linked duplicate. Configuring your `show` relationship with `lazy='dynamic'` should do the trick.